# how to sign mini-filter driver with new HLK test

Tags: windows, testing, driver, signing

we have a mini-filter driver that want to run in windows 7 to 11.
if I understand correctly Microsoft introduced a new way for signing and release drivers.
so we need pass HLK and HCK test to sign driver by Microsoft but my question is that mini-filter driver (file system filter driver) can pass HLK and HCK test?

(is there another way to sign driver without pass HLK and HCK test?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a category for file system filter drivers in HLK and HCK kits.
You can also automate the certification process by using HCK-CI project: https://github.com/HCK-CI

Comment: Does Cross Signing still work for Windows 10 or Windows 7, or has it expired?

Comment: Cross certificates are expired https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/deprecation-of-software-publisher-certificates-and-commercial-release-certificates